# Cannot load a particular website into UIWebView: NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have seen multiple questions on this about certificates being the problem but none of the answers seem to work. This is the error I get when trying to run it: **NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)**

Here is the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewControllerWebAdvisor : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *mainMenuButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *loadingLabel;

@end
```

Here is the .m file:

```
#import "ViewControllerWebAdvisor.h"

@interface ViewControllerWebAdvisor ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerWebAdvisor

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tookOutSiteNameBecauseIConsiderItPersonal.ca"];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:requestURL];

    _mainMenuButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    _mainMenuButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    _mainMenuButton.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    _loadingLabel.text = @"LOADING...";
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    _loadingLabel.text = @"";
}

@end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Error -9813 is "cert chain not verified by root" so tell us more about the certificates involved.

Comment: How can I tell you more? I am not that good with certificate related stuff so please instruct me :P

Comment: Well for starters, was it self-generated?

Comment: If by self-generated you mean made my be? No if that is the case. It is a school website used for registering for courses, checking transcript, etc.

Comment: So the certificates have been generated by a well-known provider?  While I'm no expert in this field, it looks like there is no root certificate available to the app.  You will need to look into the "chain of trust" of the certificates and figure out how it works.

Comment: Yes I would say it was generated by a "well-known provider" since it is a university site. I am not very knowledgeable when it comes to certificates. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No, by "well know provider" I mean Verisign and the such; the University will not be trusted by default.  You will need to take some time to learn about the "chain of trust" involved with certificate exchange in order to be able to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple document, you can disable the certificate checks by the below code. Add them in appDelegate.m

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController) 
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host 
{ 
return YES; 
} 
@end
```

This link is The Apple document https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012884-CH1-SECINTRODUCTION

Hope it helps